# MySQL ORDER BY RAND() with WHERE clause any better?

Tags: mysql, performance

I understand `ORDER BY RAND()` is slow (am using it to get a random subset of data). But I wonder whether if there is a `WHERE` clause or a filtering function like `JOIN`, will it improve things? My DB size can grow as times goes by. But if I expect the `WHERE` to limit the number of records to say 1000, `ORDER BY RAND()` will work only with that 1000 records correct?

---

**In case you want more detail**

What I am doing is actually generating winners for a lucky draw. So I want to randomly select a few winners. Simple example is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM luckydrawchance
WHERE luckydraw = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

But some users might have more chances of winning, so I am thinking

```
SELECT * FROM luckydrawchance
WHERE luckydraw = 1
ORDER BY RAND() * (-chances)
LIMIT 5
```

Maybe instead of `RAND() * (-chances)` I need something else (I read this does not give the right probability distribution) but just to give you an idea.

Comment: Why do you need to `ORDER BY RAND`? Are you trying to select a fixed number of randomly selected records from the table?

Comment: I agree whith @Asad, you have to find out what you really want or need.

Comment: @Asad, I want to get a random subset of data

Comment: Is your index sequential, and if so, does it have gaps due to deletions? If this is the case, you can get a random subset fairly efficiently by doing the following: 1) get the number of rows in the table, 2) generate k numbers in the range 1 to N, where N is the row count and k is your desired sample size, 3) join your table with these k numbers on the id field.

Comment: You can definitely reduce your whole table by something like `where rand() < 0.01` and afterwards order by rand() again and limit it. If the query gives too little number of results just repeat it, and make your filtering limit big enough to give a few times the number of the winners.

Comment: Sorry, that should be "does it **not** have gaps due to deletions"? Gaps will make the result unpredictable, since the randomly generated number might not actually be an ID in the table.

Comment: @Asad, What do you mean by sequential index? I read abt that method. I am trying to balance the increasing complexity of code vs performance. Gaps can occur due to the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @JiewMeng What I mean is: does your table have an autogenerated field that goes `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... N` for the N records it contains? If so, you can very inexpensively obtain N, then inexpensively obtain a quantity of numbers (in your question 1000) between 1 and N, then find all records where the value of the sequential field occurs in your randomly selected set of 1000 numbers. The problem with this is if records in your table get deleted (or are disqualified due to some other WHERE condition), which can result in the numbers you generated not existing in the table.

Comment: The slightly more expensive (but bulletproof) alternative is to first have `SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS rank, t.* FROM <rest of your query goes here>` as a subquery or view, then do the same thing I described above against this subquery/view.

Comment: Even if the IDs are gapless, not every id has set luckydraw = 1 I guess. So I would not go for guessing a number.

Comment: @flaschenpost Since there is really no way around a full table scan (the only way to make `where rand() < 0.01` fair is to use it without `LIMIT`), I would go with the approach of generating the row numbering yourself against the filtered subset where `luckydraw=1` (and whatever other conditions are needed). Then following the approach I described above.

Comment: @Asad as I said in my EDIT2: `select * from users where rand() < [part] order by rand() limit numwinners` with a sufficient big [part], or you make fixed column with a rand value which you update nightly.

Comment: @flaschenpost Right, so this is exactly as expensive as the operation I described above. In my case a `rank` field is computed for every row in the table, in your case `RAND()` is computed for every row in the table. The differences I can see are that in the former case, there is no possibility of coming up short and having to repeat the query, and there is no possibility of ending up with a large subset from the `where` that you have to do an expensive `ORDER BY RAND()` on.

Comment: @Asad could you make an answer of your rank? I think it could be faster than `order by rand()`, since int-arithmetic is used. But it is a bit more programming, to get the List of rand-integers and to retrieve N correctly (InnoDB _is_ slow for that question).

Answer (score 1):

Joining other tables will actually make things worse because to order by rand(), MySQL copies the result to a temporary table. The bigger and more complex the data to copy, the slower the query. As for `WHERE`, I can't give an absolute answer but I expect sorting a smaller subset to be faster than sorting the whole table. Using `EXPLAIN` on your query should help you to understand how it is executed.

Comment: It says "*Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort*". So I guess its doing the `ORDER BY RAND()` on the subset of data?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: From your extra information it is clear, that the fair randomness is important, but you need only a few rows and you need them not very often. So I would combine two steps. `numrows` is very roughly the number of rows in table, `numwinners` the number of wanted winners

- calculate `part` =  `5 * numwinners` / `numrows`
- query your data in the way

  ```
  select * from users where rand() < [part] order by rand() limit numwinners
  ```

If it gets less then `numwinners` rows (very rare, but could happen), then repeat the query.

EDIT: more clarified

If you just want an arbitrary subset of your data for a one-shot analysis, you should find out how much your sample data is compared to the whole table. Say it is a bit less than 0.1% and 1000 rows, then you could try

```
where rand() < 0.001
LIMIT 1000 // EDIT of course you should use limit
```

This also creates tons of rand() numbers, but does not have to order your data for those rand() numbers. You MUST adopt the 0.001 to your needs, and there is no guarantee for the good solution. If you make the number too small or if you just are unlucky (random!), you get too little data. If you make it too big, you always get only older (or only newer) entries depending on sorting.

If you need a random sample very often, then you could assign a fixed field with a random number, but you have to be a bit careful reading the sample. If you spread the range `[ 0, 1 ]` to your lines and want a fair sample, then you could make a check-random number between `[ 0.1, 0.9 ]` and read all data within `[check - 0.1, check+0.1]`. You could reshuffle the assigned random numbers every now and then (at night, for example).

Comment: The problem with this is that there is a vanishing probability that you get the entire table. You'll usually get a percentage close to 0.1% of the records, but you could also theoretically load a billion records and OutOfMemory your program, or anywhere in between.

Comment: @Asad you are right, I use this with limit always, but I will edit the answer.

Comment: This is better, but now it suffers from the "naive reservoir sampling" problem. Rows further down in the default ordering have lower probability of being selected than rows higher up.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any attempt to get a random 5 rows out of a 1000-row table will hit all 1000 rows.  flaschenpost's will fetch somewhere between 5 and 1000; it will vary.

[Here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) are the only really efficient random fetchers I know of.  You have not provided enough details about your table for me to pick among the five for you.